# Why do my cucumbers in brine have a metallic aftertaste?

Tags: brining, pickling, pickles, cucumbers

I pickle cucumbers in brine using about 45 grams of salt per litre of water, stored in a mason jar at room temperature for about a week.

I season them with fresh dill, smashed garlic, a whole chilli pepper, mustard seeds, bay leaf and whole black pepper.

As far as I can tell the cucumbers pickle successfully, but have a metallic aftertaste.

What might be causing the aftertaste and how can I solve it?

Comment: If you taste the brine, say, 4-12 hours after starting the pickles, is the same taste there?

Comment: I'll check next time I prepare them. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It seems like the most important question to narrow down the source is, is this taste a product of fermentation or does it diffuse out from one of the ingredients. Tasting when there’s been enough time to steep the ingredients but not enough time for fermentation to begin in earnest will tell you that.

Comment: I assume you are not using iodized salt?

Comment: @Esther Correct. I'm using ordinary kosher salt

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the salt you used has anti caking agent in it. It gives brines that unpleasant tin roof taste. Try using as pure a sodium chloride you can find for brines. You really don't want any additives or trace elements in the salt you use for brines.